# Using fiddler to capture video steam url

Tags: url, video, fiddler

I'm trying to capture the video steam url for a video I have running in my web browser. On fiddler I can see the css, plugins and images in the traffic that relate to the video but I don't see anything about the video stream. Is there anything I can do to see that?
[image]
On this [link](http://www.ispyconnect.com/userguide-connecting-cameras.aspx) I saw they used fiddler to find the url for a video stream.

Comment: So, could you find a way to capture video stream URL? I still can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most sites I used before one of the `.html` or `.js` files has an url to the video stream.

It often starts with `rtmp://`, so you could search in for it in a files response text.

Comment: Yes, whether you see a request to the video stream's URL very much depends on whether the stream is using HTTP or HTTPS for delivery.

Comment: What I have in the picture above is pretty much all I'm getting. I don't see anything there that could relate to video other than /cgi-bin/mediaport.cgi?

Comment: I can't tell more about this since I don't know which site it is. In addition to the files above you yould also search the `.asp` files.